# Picasso.with(this) проблема с этой строкой

Tags: java, android, android-studio, picasso

Picasso.with(this) работает в основном классе а в созданном что писать на место this?

Comment: контекст туда передайте. активити

Comment: методу требуется "живой" экземпляр класса `Context` (полученный из активити или `View`, а не просто `new Context()`)

Comment: да. я уже разобрался. cпс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Передайте туда Context.
getApplicationContext  к примеру

Comment: Да, уже решил проблему так)

Comment: @GreenMap я просто не увидел,чтобы вы отметили какой-либо ответ правильным,поэтому и написал)

Comment: Ааа. Я недавно тут. Не знал что тут можно отмечать правильные ответы